# R notebook freezes RStudio server

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I'm using R notebook in RStudio server on an ununtu server.

In the last few days, the screen freezes when I access the server. I tried rstudio-server restart, rstudio-server stop and then rstudio-server stop, deleting cache, nothing helped.
The only thing that did make Rstudio server work again was deleting /home/usr/.local/share/rstudio directory.But when I load my project and then the notebook, it freezes again.
What can I do?
Thanks in advance